# Node.js how to make cronjob task to run one time and not multiple time when working with clusters/workers?

Tags: node.js, cron, cluster-computing

I have 4 clusters/workers running on my node server (exclude the master).
I tried to place a cronjob in some route which is executed 4 times, instead of one.

I have solved this by doing this:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
io.set('origins', '*:*');
var client = require('redis').createClient();
var limiter = require('express-limiter')(app, client);
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs("mongodb://user:passip:port/dbname", []);
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var request = require('request');
var fcm = require('./routes/fcm');
var cm = require('./routes/customModules.js');
var Excel = require('exceljs');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var Joi = require('joi');

if(cluster.isMaster) {

    var numWorkers = require('os').cpus().length;
    console.log('Master cluster setting up ' + numWorkers + ' workers...');

    for(var i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('online', function(worker) {
        console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' is online');
    });

    cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
        console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' stopped with code: ' + code + ', and signal: ' + signal);
        console.log('Starting a new worker');
        cluster.fork();
    });

    new CronJob('1 * * * * *', function() {

      // my cronjob task here!

    }, null, true, 'Asia/Jerusalem');

} else {

  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
  var cors = require('cors');
  var server = require('http').createServer(app);
  var io = require('socket.io')(server);
  var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
  io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
  io.set('origins', '*:*');
  var client = require('redis').createClient();
  var limiter = require('express-limiter')(app, client);
  var mongojs = require('mongojs');
  var db = mongojs("mongodb://user:passip:port/dbname", []);
  var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
  var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
  var request = require('request');
  var fcm = require('./routes/fcm');
  var cm = require('./routes/customModules.js');
  var Excel = require('exceljs');
  var fs = require('fs');
  var path = require('path');
  var Joi = require('joi');

  app.use(cors());

  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/src'));

  require('./routes/sockets')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request, fcm);
  require('./routes/userServer')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request, fcm, limiter, Joi, cm);
  require('./routes/ridesServer')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request, limiter, cm);
  require('./routes/offersServer')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request, limiter, cm);
  require('./routes/notificationsServer')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request);
  require('./routes/scopeServer')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request, fcm);
  require('./routes/excelServer')(app, io, mongojs, db, ObjectId, CronJob, request, fcm, Excel, fs, path, limiter);

  server.listen("8080", function() {
    console.log("Connected to db and listening on port 8080");
  });

}
```

It works.
But its about efficiency, am I doing this okay or that someone here could find a better solution for this?

Notice that I defined the main variables twice, once in top for the master class to be functioning, and once again, for each worker.

Is this a good way of working?

Thanks.